# Jquery modal with dropdownlist changing contents

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog, postback

I am having problems with jquery dialog and postback inside the dialog.
I wonder if this is possible: An aspx page with a button to open a jquery modal dialog.
Inside this dialog there is a dropdownlist and a checkboxlist.
On the dropdownlist OnSelectedIndexChanged event go to the database and populate the checkboxlist with the result dataset.
All this without closing the jquery dialog.

Thanks

Here is my Code:
**Default.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-ui.1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.smoothness.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Script/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Jquery Dialog - ListView</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="MasterScriptManager" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <input type="button" id="btnOpen" value="Open Dialog" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="myDialog" style="display:none;">
            <input type="button" id="btnClose" value="Cancel" />

            <asp:DropDownList ID="Grupo_DropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                CssClass="DropDownList"
                DataSourceID="Grupos_SqlDataSource"
                Enabled="true"
                DataValueField="ValueField" DataTextField="TextField"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="Grupo_DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="MembrosGrupo_CheckBoxList" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="MembrosGrupo_SqlDataSource"
                DataValueField="CheckedAndUsercode" DataTextField="FullName"
                RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                OnDataBound="MembrosGrupo_CheckBoxList_DataBound">
            </asp:CheckBoxList>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Grupos_SqlDataSource" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
                SelectCommand="aplicacoes.GestaoTarefas_Grupos_GetList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="Usercode" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" DefaultValue="fefmnunes" />
            </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MembrosGrupo_SqlDataSource" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
                SelectCommand="aplicacoes.GestaoTarefas_Grupo_Membros_GetList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
                OnSelecting="MembrosGrupo_SqlDataSource_Selecting">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="Usercode" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" DefaultValue="fefmnunes" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Grupo_DropDownList" Direction="Input" Name="Grupo" />
            </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace JqueryDialogListView
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
        protected void Grupo_DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 1;
    }

    protected void MembrosGrupo_CheckBoxList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList cbl = (CheckBoxList)sender;
        foreach (ListItem item in cbl.Items)
        {

            string[] words = item.Value.Split('|');
            string x = words[0];
            item.Selected = bool.Parse(words[0]);
        }
    }

    protected void MembrosGrupo_SqlDataSource_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] words = e.Command.Parameters[1].Value.ToString().Split('|');
        e.Command.Parameters[1].Value = words[0];
    }
}
```

**dialog.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$("#myDialog").dialog({
    dialogClass: 'DynamicDialogStyle',
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 238,
    title: "...Whatever...",
    close: function () {

        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
        $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
    }
}).parent().appendTo("form1");

jQuery("#btnOpen").click(function (e) {
    jQuery('#myDialog').dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
    jQuery('#myDialog').dialog('open');
});

jQuery("#btnClose").click(function (e) {
    jQuery('#myDialog').dialog('close');
});
```

});

Comment: Yes it is possible . Please post your relevant code where you are stuck

Comment: Thanks RahulB. How can I publish the code files?

Comment: You can add the code in the question block itself . Just select the code snippet and Ctrl+K for converting it into a code block

Comment: Thanks. I publish all the code. Its a small project. I'm having this issue. When I change the dropdownlist selection, the entire page postback and the dialog closes.